# why couchdb and fauxton don't work correctly in windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, couchdb

Current situation:

After installing couchdb on windows 10 using the apache-couchdb-2.3.1.msi installer and configure its operation as a simple node with the data

User: Admin (It's for testing only) Password: Pass (Too insecure? It's for testing only!) Port: 5984 Ip: 127.0.0.1

The installation was verified: http://127.0.0.1:5984/_utils/#/verifyinstall

When creating a "test" database it is created correctly When creating a new document it is created correctly

Problem: When adding information to the created document and pressing the "Save Changes" button

Nothing happens, changes are not saved

Unmodified document:

{"_id": "e940717f486026242e9b5d9cd80023d2", "_rev": "1-967a00dff5e02add41819138abb3284d"}

Document modified (Changes are not saved)

{"_id": "e940717f486026242e9b5d9cd80023d2", "_rev": "1-967a00dff5e02add41819138abb3284d" "data": "Hello World"}

The button only works when the document has not undergone changes or when I delete the aggregated data "data" I have also tried adding the comma "," at the end of each line

{"_id": "e940717f486026242e9b5d9cd80023d2", "_rev": "1-967a00dff5e02add41819138abb3284d", "data": "Hello World",}

The same without any results, I tried using firefox and chrome, I tried to disable plugins and addons in those browsers

Comment: On Chrome, can you open the console (F12) and see if there are any errors when trying to update a document?

Comment: Consider using Photon admin panel https://github.com/ermouth/couch-photon, it seems to work at any platform – written in very old-fashoined way.

Comment: thanks photon have the same problem I solve it  changing the installation path from i:/couchdb to c:/couchdb I don't now why this work's

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your JSON is not correct.

This is your sample where a , is missing before "data"

`{"_id": "e940717f486026242e9b5d9cd80023d2","_rev": "1-967a00dff5e02add41819138abb3284d" "data": "Hello World"}`

It should be like this one

```
{"_id": "e940717f486026242e9b5d9cd80023d2",
 "_rev": "1-967a00dff5e02add41819138abb3284d",
 "data": "Hello World"
}
```

JSON syntax should be correct, otherwise it will not be saved

Comment: thanks I say and did two ways with and without "," the problem is resolved "I solve it changing the installation path from i:/couchdb to c:/couchdb I don't now why this work's"